# How to use JSONB data in a virtual dataType?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I define the following object in my model:

```
result: {
  type: DataTypes.JSONB,
  defaultValue: {},
  jsonSchema: {
    schema: {
      type: 'object'
    }
  }
}
```

The json data stored in this object looks like this:

```
"result": {
    "score": {
        "scaled": 1,
        "raw": 8,
        "min": 7,
        "max": 10
    },
    "success": true,
    "completion": true,
    "duration": "2H30M"
}
```

Now I try to create a virtual field with the value off success. I tried doing this but without any luck.

```
result_success: {
  type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
  get () {
    return this.getDataValue('result').success;
  }
},
```

But this does not get returned when I make a request via this model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Here is an example:

`index.ts`:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import assert from 'assert';

class SomeEntity extends Model {
  public id!: number;
  public result!: any;
  public result_success!: boolean;
}
SomeEntity.init(
  {
    result: {
      type: DataTypes.JSONB,
      defaultValue: {},
    },
    result_success: {
      type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
      get(this: SomeEntity) {
        return this.getDataValue('result').success;
      },
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'SomeEntities' },
);

(async function test() {
  try {
    await sequelize.sync({ force: true });
    // seed
    const entity = await SomeEntity.create({
      result: {
        score: { scaled: 1, raw: 8, min: 7, max: 10 },
        success: true,
        completion: true,
        duration: '2H30M',
      },
    });
    assert(entity.result_success, 'The value of the virtual field result_success should be truthy');
    console.log('entity.result_success: ', entity.result_success);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    await sequelize.close();
  }
})();
```

After executing above code, check the data records in the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "SomeEntities";
 id |                                                      result
----+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"score": {"max": 10, "min": 7, "raw": 8, "scaled": 1}, "success": true, "duration": "2H30M", "completion": true}
(1 row)
```

And the log printed, the `entity.result_success` virtual field returns `true` as expected:

```sh
{ POSTGRES_HOST: '127.0.0.1',
  POSTGRES_PORT: '5430',
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'testpass',
  POSTGRES_USER: 'testuser',
  POSTGRES_DB: 'node-sequelize-examples' }
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "SomeEntities" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "SomeEntities" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "SomeEntities" ("id"   SERIAL , "result" JSONB DEFAULT '{}', PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'SomeEntities' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "SomeEntities" ("id","result") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1) RETURNING *;
entity.result_success:  true
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/examples/stackoverflow/59877140